# AbstractController ActionNotFound for failure rails 3 using google oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am using google oauth2 when i log in using google, after i select my account and hit enter this error show up.

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
The action 'failure' could not be found for OmniauthCallbacksController
```

I am so stumped! What do i do wrong?

**controller for omniauth**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
    def google_oauth2
        auth_details = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        if auth_details.info['email'].split("@")[1] == "company.net"
            user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
            if user.persisted?
                flash.notice = "Signed in Through Google!"
                sign_in_and_redirect user
            else
                session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
                flash.notice = "Please provide a password"
                redirect_to new_user_registration_url
            end
        else
            render :text => "Sorry this site is for company employees only"
        end
    end
end
```

in intializers/devise.rb 
i have the config.omniauth requirements

**Trace**

```
the error show this process actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb
```

**and this is the line it highlight**

```
unless action_name = method_for_action(action_name)
    raise ActionNotFound, "The action" '#{action}' could not be found for #{self.class.name}"
end
```

Comment: Hi, what is trace? Thank you

Comment: Naomi, the error's backtrace. There is no failure method on the screen and I don't know what code called it.

Comment: Thank you, I add what it show me in error, but its not something i write

Answer (score 1):

I see. The `failure` method should belong to Devise's controller. You didn't inherit the controller from Devise but ApplicationController so this method can't be found.

Since you are implementing Omniauth based on Devise, this controller need to inherit from Devise's.

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

Or better, add a namespace User because the controller is in 'app/controllers/users`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

Comment: Thank you very much! how can i make the change do i need to migrate? or i can do it manually?

Comment: For non-namespaced version, you just need to rename the controller, that's all. For namespaced, you need to change name, and define the routes if you havn't done that: `devise_for :user, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}`. No need migration as this is for controller.

Comment: I used the namespaced version
When I do this i get uninitialized constant Users do you know why that may happen?

Comment: You need to restart server after changing constant.